# Reading files in dictionary and returning file value if dataframe column value is present

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows called df1 :

```
change      info      level
R6J         P123D     1 
K4B         BNJIA     1
S23P        WWGFT     1
Y9O         77-ER     2
L243Z       BNJIA     1
M013        22HF      3
```

and a dictionary (with thousands of keys) with the "info" column as keys. All file names beginning with the key are values:

```
dict = {'P123D':['P123D-334.csv'], 'BNJIA':['BNJIA-32G.csv', 'BNJIA-23A.csv'], 'WWGFT':['WWGFT-0RTF.csv', 'WWGFT-IIJK.csv'], '77-ER':['77ER-LLK.csv'], '22HF':['22HF-HFG76.csv']}
```

I'm looking to check if the strings in df1['info'] match any key in dict. If they match then read the files associated with the keys values and look for the string in df1['change'] on the same row as the string taken from df1['info'].

If the string from df1['change'] is in the file, then take the value from column 3 and append to df1.

example of file contents:

```
col1    col2    col3
P34F    5       2.3
R6J     12      3.5
X65D    2       -1.4
```

Desired output: Obviously the other rows for new_col would also be full if a value is found

```
change      info      level    new_col
R6J         P123D     1        3.5
K4B         BNJIA     1        
S23P        WWGFT     1
Y9O         77-ER     2
L243Z       BNJIA     1
M013        22HF      3
```

I have tried a few different things but can't seem to solve.

```
lst = []
for k,v in new_dict.items():
  if k in df1.iloc[:,2]:
    lst.append(df1.iloc[:,0])

for v in new_dict.values():
  if v.split('-') in df1.iloc[:,2]:
    with open(v, 'r') as f:
      for i in lst:
        if i in f.read():
          print(i)
```

Comment: why is `col2` absent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this example to create the `new_col` from the dict and dataframe:

```
def custom_func(x, dct):
    if x.info in dct:
        for v in dct[x.info]:
            tmp_df = pd.read_csv(v, sep=r'\s+')
            v = tmp_df.loc[tmp_df['col1'] == x.change, 'col3']
            if len(v) > 0:
                return v.iat[0]

dct = {'P123D':['P123D-334.csv'], 'BNJIA':['BNJIA-32G.csv', 'BNJIA-23A.csv'], 'WWGFT':['WWGFT-0RTF.csv', 'WWGFT-IIJK.csv'], '77-ER':['77ER-LLK.csv'], '22HF':['22HF-HFG76.csv']}
df['new_col'] = df[['change', 'info']].apply(lambda x: custom_func(x, dct), axis=1)
print(df)
```